# How do I assign a nested or child html div that does NOT have an ID to a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

Here is the format of the html structure:

```
<div class="material-list">
  <div class="wapf-field-label">...</div>
  <div class="wapf-field-input">
    <select data-field-id="369175" name="wapf[field_26326]" class="wapf-input">
      ... options ...
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use Javascript on the select list, but it's a grand child of .material-list and doesn't have an html id. How can I add that select list to a Javascript variable?

Comment: `const list = document.querySelector(".material-list select")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple and you have a few ways:

```
const select1 = document.querySelector('.material-list select')
```

Or you can to this:

```
const list = document.querySelector('.material-list')
const select2 = list.querySelector('select')
```

Another way is to look select by data attribute in your case:

```
const select = document.querySelector('select[data-field-id="369175"]')
```

Be aware that document.querySelector will always return first element so if you have a multiple select elements this then only first select will be returned.

So if you want to get all select elements inside material-list then this should work:

```
const allSelectElements = document.querySelectorAll('.material-list select')
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted yours. I am using const sel = querySelector('.material-list) and console.log(sel) and the console is telling me that sel is null. Why would that happen?

Comment: @MDoulos `const sel = document.querySelector('.material-list')` did you forget to add `document.querySelector`?

Comment: This is exactly what I have. Copied and pasted: const sel = document.querySelector('.material-list select')
console.log(sel)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/ba92k4rx/2/ here is the fiddle. Please post your HTML then because you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I've resolved why it wasn't working. I was loading the Javascript in the wp_head instead of the wp_footer so it executed BEFORE the class .material-list had been added to the div. Thank you!

Comment: I see, you can still use script in the wp_head just make sure to add async or defer. More about here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-defer-async#:~:text=%3E-,Async%20vs%20Defer,order%20as%20they%20are%20called.